# MySQL CREATE TABLE syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to create an sql table but don't know What's wrong here? My SQL syntax is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE '__admin'('id' int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 'name' VARCHAR(32)     NOT NULL, 'password' VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL)ENGINE=MYISAM;
```

I get an error message saying:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
>   ''id' int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 'name' VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, 'pass' 
>   at line 1

Need a quick help please? Thanks

Comment: Remove quotes from table name and column names.

Comment: Use backticks for table adn column name,quotes are for strings. \`id\`

Comment: Backticks are not necessary here, the only case when backticks are necessary is when the identifiers in use are one of the MySQL reserved words: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: Don't quote/backtick your column & table names.  They only add visual clutter and are just one more way for you to make syntax errors.  The only reason you need them is if you have a column name that is a reserved word, and using column names that are reserved words is a terrible idea, so that's two bad habits you can avoid at once.

Answer (score 0):

Need to learn SQL syntax first?

Identifiers have to be put in `backticks`, not single quotes

```
CREATE TABLE `__admin`(`id`
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

as stated in one of the comments, backticks are not a necessity.

`CREATE TABLE _admin (table attributes)`  would work just fine.. also some software may need you to specify the db engine when creating the table such as sequal pro for mac.. if you are linking your tables using foreign keys then add `ENGINE=INNODB` at the end of your statement

so it will be

`CREATE TABLE _admin(id INT PRIMARY KEY, etc.)ENGINE=INNODB;`

hope this helps